# Can't get remote data to render in Select2

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-select2

I am using mysql database to retrieve data and show it into Select2. Right now, the  search data is being showed in the preview of the get call. But not in the options of the Select2. Even though I am receiving the correct response, i can't get it added into the options of the select box

[image: This is the preview I get which is correct search response]

Below is my Javascript code

```
$("#selecter").select2({
    ajax: {
        url: "index.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                q: params.term // search term
            };
        },
        processResults: function (data) {
            return {
                results: data
            };
        },
        cache: true
    },
    escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
    minimumInputLength: 2
});
```

and here is the php code

```
if(isset($_GET['q'])){
    $urlparam_name = $_GET['q'] ."%";
    $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'customerdatabase_13030') or die("Error " .mysqli_error($link));
    $sql = "
        SELECT `customer_13030`.`custID`, `customer_13030`.`name`
        FROM `customer_13030`
        WHERE `customer_13030`.`custID` like '$urlparam_name' OR    `customer_13030`.`name` like '$urlparam_name' 
        GROUP BY `customer_13030`.`custID` ASC
    ";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die("Error " .mysqli_error($link));
    $rows = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $rows[] =array(
            'id' => $row['custID'],
            'name' => $row['name']
        );
    }
    echo json_encode($rows);
}
```

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually building your queries like that. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: What's up with the "Type your name"-box after the json data in the preview? Is your PHP code located in the top of the file that shows the search-box? Then you need to have an `exit;` after your echo (which is good practice to always have) or the script will continue to output everything after, making the json response invalid.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I can't believe missing the exit; was the issue!!! It works fine now, god I am an amateur

Comment: If that makes you an amateur, then we all are. Missing things like that happens to everyone :-)